# Connection getting refused to socket.io server on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up a a micro EC2 instance on AWS. Currently, I am using the free tier in Oregon. There are two problems which I am facing.

1. When I try to SSH the instance using the public DNS, it says host does not exist but when I try conencting it using the public IP, it connects to it. What setting is needed to use the public DNS ?
2. I have opened the SSH client using the IP address. I want to set up my application which needs Node.js and MongoDB. I installed Node.js using [this](http://iconof.com/blog/how-to-install-setup-node-js-on-amazon-aws-ec2-complete-guide/)
   Next I installed MongoDB using [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/)
   Then I connected to my instance using Filezilla and uploaded my code to it. I then start my node application which uses socket.io.

When I try to connect to socket.io server using web browser, I get a message which says connection refused "error 111". I have opened TCP port 80 in instance's security groups. In iptables, I have forwarded port 80 to 8080, but still it does not work. I have also checked that the firewall is disabled in ec2. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if all of the necessary ports are open on Amazon Security Policy?

What you can do is to allow all traffic on Amazon Security Policy for test and see if the connection goes well or not.

You might also check if you need access DB from outside. In that case, you also have to open the mongodb port and setup mongodb correctly as well.

Other tools that might useful to test firewall and connection issue will be tcpdump and syslog file

For the dns issue, did you try to nslookup on that name and see if the IP shown matches your server IP?

As Amazon gives a long DNS hostname for the server, I always use my own domain name. It's much easier. 
example : ec2.domainname.com, which points to the Amazon IP address

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved now..
For the DNS issue, earlier I needed proxy to access internet, so I guess the DNS name was not getting resolved. When I tried using proxy free internet, I was able to ssh using public DNS.

And regarding connection to socket.io, I used port 8080 instead of 80 and used "sudo node main.js" to run my node file. Now I am able to connect to the socket.io server and MongoDB. 
Another thing which I want to ask is that would running the node file with sudo rights create some security issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! That also worked for me. I had the same problem trying to connect through sockets (http://myipaddress:3000) to a node.js server, i tried opening ports on the actual ec2 instance and disabling the firewall through SSH but nothing worked. Had to go to Security Groups on the ec2 console and open a new inbound tcp rule enabling that port